# Is using LIMIT and OFFSET in MySQL less expensive than returning the full set of records?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, offset

It might be a silly question but I am just curious about what goes on behind the curtains.

If I want to paginate database records I can either use LIMIT and OFFSET or simply get all the records and extrapolate the ones I want with more code.

I know the second option is absolutely silly, I just want to know if it is more expensive

If I use LIMIT and OFFSET will the database grab just what I ask for, or will internally get all the records matching my query (even hundreds of thousands) and then use internally a starting index (OFFSET) and an ending index (OFFSET + LIMIT) to get the requested subset of records?

I don't even know if I used the right words to describe the doubt I have, I hope someone can shed some light.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it would be more expensive, for two reasons.

1)  Mysql will optimize internally to only calculate the rows that it needs, rather than retrieving them all internally.  Note that this optimization is a lot less if you have an order by in your query, because then mysql has to match and sort all of the rows in the dataset, rather than stopping when it finds the first X in your limit.

2)  When all the records are returned, they all need to be transmitted over the wire from the database to your application server.  That can take time, especially for medium to large data sets.

Comment: Wonderful answer, and good call on the order by, but most of the times (especially when we have limit and offset which assume a pagination environment most of the times) we do need to order the queries. But again, great answer, thanks a lot

Comment: depending on how you build your query, order by may, or may not, require the database to generate more rows than it must return.  If there's a solid 1 to 1 correspondence between the index used for the order and the resulting number of rows, for instance if the same columns appears in both the order by and group by clauses, the database *may* be able to skip the rows trimmed off by the offset.  At very least, if the query can be planned around the same index used for the order, the trailing rows, trimmed by the limit, won't need to be generated.

Comment: TokenMacGuy has a good point, it is possible to optimize the index to match the results, as a specialized case, to optimize the processing.

Comment: So, assuming I have a scenario where, for good reasons, I need to return the full set of records available and then do some processing and also paginate the results, what numbers will keep me on the safe side? Meaning with this: how many records can I safely return from the query to the app knowing it won't be expensive enough to become an issue compared to the limit offset approach?

Comment: Like most performance based questions, the only way to answer it is to test it.  Try one setting, and see how it does.  Then adjust a setting and try again.

Answer (score 2):

The difference can be enormous. Not only is the network difference big sometimes (a few rows vs hundreds to thousands), but the number of rows the database needs to find can be large also. For example, if you ask for 10 rows, the database can stop after finding 10 rows, rather than having to check every row.

Whenever possible, use LIMIT and OFFSET.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at the moment I am trying to think of a way to do it, but my scenario is a bit complicated:

**The case**

Wordpress Website, I am building a photo gallery where I have pagination, posts view (see the lists of posts containing photos) and images view (you see, in the same page, a full list of photos coming from those posts, paginated as well).I am
1) Retrieving all posts in the photos category
2) Retrieving all the image attachments posts that are children of posts of point (1)
3) showing the right content, with the right layout, and the right pagination with php logic